# Set property (type interface) without implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, moq

I'm creating some UnitTests and want to mock a service which returns a `Thing` object with a `FileInformation` property that implements a `IFileInformation` interface.

How do I fill in / mock the `Thing` without writing a implementation for this interface?

```
public interface IFileInformation
{
   string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Thing
{
   public IFileInformation FileInformation { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) lib for my UnitTests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it was easier than I thought.

Using Moq to mock the interface.

```
Mock<IFileInformation> fileInformation = new Mock<IFileInformation>();
fileInformation.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns("whatever.txt");

Thing serviceResult = new Thing();
serviceResult.FileInformation = fileInformation.Object;
```

Comment: Good stuff, that's what I was getting at. You can mock the interface and just new up the concrete implementation of Thing.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How can you access `serviceResult.FileInformation` when the member `FileInformation` is a **`private`** (auto) property, according to your question post?

Comment: I can't, I can understand the confusion and altered the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to create the interface, you have no option but to new up the Thing class in your unit tests.

```
var sut = new Thing();
```

Comment: How does this help filling the `FileInformation` property on `Thing`?